# How do I establish a connection to a remote database?

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform, config, lamp

I'm just trying to understand the general concept.

I have a **LAMP stack virtual machine instance** on **Google Cloud Platform** with a MySQL database.

I have created a database already via the phpMyAdmin web interface.

My index.php file has php code which makes use of the data in that database.

**Important**: The project files are stored on my computer at home (locally).

**Problem**: I have a config.php and index.php files in my project, but don't know what I'm supposed to do to connect / "talk" to the database that's on the GCP vm instance.

I tried changing the 'DBHOST' value in my config.php to the database hostname but that obviously didn't do anything b/c I don't see how that's enough information to connect to the database.

This is my ***config.php*** file

```
<?php
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBNAME', 'business_covid');
define('DBUSER', 'testuser');
define('DBPASS', 'hidden');
define('DBCONNSTRING','mysql:dbname=business_covid;charset=utf8mb4');
?>
```

Do I need more info than this and is a correctly configured config.php file all that is needed to connect to a database?

Comment: You are not saying much, I presume that if you state these then you have created the db already and can connect with it outside of php or with phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: Have you tried using MySQLi or PDO? -> Recommended : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: This is a pretty broad question around connectivity. There are a lot of questions that you'll need to answer first, like, where is your remote database that you want to connect to? Is the database on a local to you machine and you want your PHP pages on GCP to connect to your machine locally? Or are you trying to run a Cloud SQL instance on GCP and you want to connect to that? Broadly speaking, that dbhost variable is what you'll change to point at the new database. But there will be more involved steps depending on where that database lives.

Comment: @Shlomtzion yes the database is created and I connect via phpMyAdmin web interface provided in the GCP

Comment: @GabeWeiss Yes, it's Cloud LAMP instance on GCP that I'm trying to connect to

Comment: Did you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Assuming you want to remotely connect to MySQL VM instance. Here's the guide on [remote access to MySQL on Comoute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/mysql-remote-access?hl=en#improve_mysql_installation_security). This guide will help you set up/configure on VM instance side to allow remote access on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this way?**

```
$username = 'testuser';

$password = 'hidden';

$dbName = 'business_covid';

$dbHost = "127.0.0.1";

// Connect using TCP

$dsn = sprintf('mysql:dbname=%s;host=%s', $dbName, $dbHost);

// Connect to the database

$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $connConfig);
```

**See the link for additional information:**
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: See the link for additional information: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#php